# Find out if Azure AD user has role assignment for a specific Azure Storage Account ADLS Gen2 container?

Tags: azure

Have Azure Storage account with ADLS Gen2 containers. The permissions for users get added by code but what it does is go to the storage container > Access Control (IAM) > Roles > Storage Blob Data Contributor > Then adds a user, group, or service principle.

Is there an easy way via python to be able to check if a user or service principle is in a specific role (such as Storage Blob Data Contributor) for a specific container?

I've attached a screenshot of the screen in azure that I'm wanting to replicate the functionality it does in python.

I've tried Role Assignments - List For Scope with a filter but it does not seem to return the same.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qV5c.png)

Answer (score 0):

One of the options you could try is using the Rest API [Get Container ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl). This will provide you a list of the the entities who have access to the container. You can run a quick search in this list to verify the access.

I couldn't find anything similar in the Python SDK.